# Bypassing load balancer to specific server for different web apps

Tags: java, http, tomcat, http-headers, load-balancing

I have 2 webservers in load balanced environment and both webservers have 2 webapps deployed in their tomcat servers. Two different domain names are used to access these two web applications.

I am struck up in a situation where I have to reload something in both webservers for both web apps separately.  So I have to a send http request to each webserver and each webapp to reload (Basically I want to bypass the load-balancer).

Is there a way to add a HTTP header so that I can send my request to specific webserver at runtime for specif domain names?  Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Note:  This HTTP request can be sent from java code deployed in any one of the webserver. So basically we can assume it as the communication between the webservers within the local network.

Comment: I feel this is related to spoofing.  I tried to find this out in forums    but I haven't got a clear idea yet on how my issue can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this question is weird.
If you have a load balancer that means that you distribute the load between 2 backend servers i.e. who deploy the same applications and which must be **consistent**, meaning that both parts must have exactly the same database (since the same client could be served from one server in one connection or the other in a next request depending also on the configuration of the load balancer).
So in this case and since both parts *should* be in sync and the database essentially *mirrored* if you send a specific request that has a certain interpretation it does not matter which server receives it. The other server should also understand that this request came since the data are mirrored.
I.e. just make a specific update in the database and let the servers reload as soon as the database update is visible in the other server as well.
Unless you are not using a load balancer or you are not using it properly...

And to answer your question how to bypass the load balancer. When you use a load balancer you use either a virtual IP or a specific domain name that "points" to the load balancer and the load balancer redirects to an available server. So you could bypass the loadbalancer if you use directly the IP of the servers instead of the IP of the load balancer.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The same IP is used for different domain names for both web apps (test.myapp1.com, test.myapp2.com).  So i am not able to access the IP for the second domain.  The database is common for both the servers in load balancer.  But we store some data in java static variable (ours is J2EE app) in JVM.  And this is not common to webservers.  I appreciate your help here.

Comment: @Slowcoder:I don't really understand your comment `database is common for both the servers in load balancer`.If you mean that both deployments in `test.myapp1.com` and `test.myapp2.com` *view* the same data then just follow my answer.If not then could you explain what you mean?

Comment: I think I have found the solution for my problem.  But I need to test it thoroughly.  I provide the solution that i am going to try in Answers section.  I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I am going to try.  It seemes worked for a small proof of concept and i am going to try in actual application.

Solution:

1. The URL should be the IP address or server host name of the webserver.
   Ex: http:///
2. For the HTTP request set the "Host" header as the actual domain name that u want to access.  In my case, it is the second webapp (test.myapp2.com) that i have deployed in my tomcat.
3. Send the HTTP request.

First it worked when i tried with the "Poster" addon in firefox but it didnt work in my Java code.  It did not show any error either.  It simply ignored the "Host" header that I set.  The java library restricts overriding some of the Request header values and "Host" is one of them.  So I had to set it explicitly to accept the restricted headers.

The initial code I had is:

```
URL url = new URL("http://<IP-ADDRESS>/");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "test.myapp2.com");
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

New Fix:

```
String allowRestrictedHeader = System.getProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders");
System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://<IP-ADDRESS>/");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "test.myapp2.com");
    // use connection
    .
    .
    .
}
finally {
    if (allowRestrictedHeader == null) {
        System.clearProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders");
    } else {
        System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders",
                allowRestrictedHeader);
    }
}
```

Comment: This way 1)You are using `SUN` specific properties i.e. your code is no longer portable to different JRE 2)You bind your solution to IPs.You will *have* to know the IPs of the specific web servers for this to work.This is totally against the concept of using a load balancer where you just need to know 1 IP or domain name, the one of the load balancer

Comment: I agree with your first point.  About the 2nd, I am trying to make requests from one webserver to another within the network.  So I have the IP configurations set up and known to each other webservers.  But I don't expose the IP outside.  Basically it is a server to server communication in my case.

Comment: First of all you shouldn't know the IPs of each of the webservers.I mean once you setup your deployment you don't need to know them.Now you are introducing a dependency to know the IPs.If you are sure about what you are doing fine.But I am not sure why don't you just update the DB with a special value and have each server (regardless how many are there and what are their IPs) restart when they see the database change?

Comment: We had to keep some values in JVM in static variables and we want to avoid the restart of the servers.  Because these values get updated atleast 2 days once and restarting the server frequently is causing some concerns.  So to dynamically refresh some data that we cannot store in the database, i am taking this approach.  I do not exactly use the IP but instead I use the server host name (different from domain name).  I keep them in a property file config so that when the IP or host name changes, I can change the properties and restart the servers once.

Comment: @ Cratylus - Can you suggest something better than "sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders" property if you have ever come across this scenario before?  I would be really happy to use something that is not dependent to particular JRE.

Comment: I already mentioned an alternative.Updating the database with a specific value.Do you have a reason not to use this approach?

Comment: We store some of the raw data (lucene index files) in each webserver.  We tried having it in a common location for all webservers but the performance was not good.  So we keep those data in each webserver and we store some related objects in JVM.  The objects are specific to each webapp deployed in the webserver and these objects need to be refreshed on demand.

Comment: These data in each web server, aren't in sync?I.e. all servers "view" the same information?

Comment: The data will be in sync for each webserver.  But we need to sync the data manually in each webserver for each webapp.